# Do not render H3 tags in primefaces p:submenu

Tags: primefaces

```
<p:menu>
    <p:submenu label="Ajax Menuitems">
         ...
    </p:submenu>
</p:menu>
```

Generates the following code:

```
<li class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
     <h3>Ajax Menuitems</h3>
</li>
```

How can i disable rendering of the h3 Tag in Primefaces 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own renderer or simply hide it using css.

markup:

```
<p:menu styleClass="hide-h3">
    <p:submenu label="Ajax Menuitems">
        ...
    </p:submenu>
</p:menu>
```

css:

```
.hide-h3 li h3 {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I have chosen to write my own renderer. Using css is not an alternative from the SEO perspective.